# Incorrect value computed during a run

Tags: c++

Below is a simplified code, from a larger C++ application code, that computes and prints (in actual application values are logged) moving average of variable A. The moving averages are calculated for a pair of values (avg_2) and a triplet of values (avg_3).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float getValueA(int index)
{
    float testArr[] = {
    0.38650, 0.72049, 0.85708, 0.82308, 0.81906,
    0.82377, 0.81834, 0.82191, 0.83690, 0.84267,
    0.84844, 0.84241, 0.84477, 0.84516, 0.84646,
    0.84754, 0.84879, 0.84782, 0.84788, 0.85158,
    0.84183, 0.84480, 0.90876, 0.97010, 0.97125
    };
    return testArr[index];
}

int main()
{
    float a = 0;
    float b = 0;
    float c = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        a = getValueA(i);
        float avg_2 = (a + b) / 2.0f;
        float avg_3 = (a + b + c) / 3.0f;
        c = b;
        b = a;
        cout << "Avg_2 = " << avg_2 << " Avg_3 = " << avg_3 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For one run, the system calculated incorrect moving average of triplet of values (avg_3) after some time.

Below is the comparison of the expected values and the output values obtained from the log corresponding to the run.

| A | Expected value of avg_2 | Expected value of avg_3 | Calculated value of avg_2 as obtained from log | Calculated value of avg_3 as obtained from log | Difference in expected value and calculated value of avg_2 | Difference in expected value and calculated value of avg_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.38650 | 0.19325 | 0.12883 | 0.19325 | 0.12883 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 0.72049 | 0.55350 | 0.36900 | 0.55349 | 0.36899 | 0.00000 | 0.00001 |
| 0.85708 | 0.78879 | 0.65469 | 0.78878 | 0.65469 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 |
| 0.82308 | 0.84008 | 0.80022 | 0.84008 | 1.22139 | 0.00000 | -0.42117 |
| 0.81906 | 0.82107 | 0.83307 | 0.82107 | 1.21401 | 0.00000 | -0.38094 |
| 0.82377 | 0.82142 | 0.82197 | 0.82141 | 1.21427 | 0.00001 | -0.39230 |
| 0.81834 | 0.82106 | 0.82039 | 0.82105 | 1.21404 | 0.00001 | -0.39365 |
| 0.82191 | 0.82013 | 0.82134 | 0.82012 | 1.21342 | 0.00001 | -0.39208 |
| 0.83690 | 0.82941 | 0.82572 | 0.82940 | 1.21960 | 0.00000 | -0.39388 |
| 0.84267 | 0.83979 | 0.83383 | 0.83978 | 1.22652 | 0.00001 | -0.39269 |
| 0.84844 | 0.84556 | 0.84267 | 0.84555 | 1.23037 | 0.00001 | -0.38770 |
| 0.84241 | 0.84543 | 0.84451 | 0.84542 | 1.23028 | 0.00001 | -0.38577 |
| 0.84477 | 0.84359 | 0.84521 | 0.84359 | 1.22906 | 0.00000 | -0.38385 |
| 0.84516 | 0.84497 | 0.84411 | 0.84496 | 1.22998 | 0.00000 | -0.38587 |
| 0.84646 | 0.84581 | 0.84546 | 0.84581 | 1.23054 | 0.00000 | -0.38508 |
| 0.84754 | 0.84700 | 0.84639 | 0.84700 | 1.23133 | 0.00000 | -0.38494 |
| 0.84879 | 0.84817 | 0.84760 | 0.84817 | 1.23211 | 0.00000 | -0.38451 |
| 0.84782 | 0.84831 | 0.84805 | 0.84831 | 1.23221 | 0.00000 | -0.38416 |
| 0.84788 | 0.84785 | 0.84816 | 0.84785 | 1.23190 | 0.00000 | -0.38374 |
| 0.85158 | 0.84973 | 0.84909 | 0.84973 | 1.23315 | 0.00000 | -0.38406 |
| 0.84183 | 0.84671 | 0.84710 | 0.84670 | 1.23114 | 0.00001 | -0.38404 |
| 0.84480 | 0.84332 | 0.84607 | 0.84331 | 1.22887 | 0.00001 | -0.38280 |
| 0.90876 | 0.87678 | 0.86513 | 0.87678 | 1.25119 | 0.00000 | -0.38606 |
| 0.97010 | 0.93943 | 0.90789 | 0.93943 | 1.29295 | 0.00000 | -0.38506 |
| 0.97125 | 0.97068 | 0.95004 | 0.97067 | 1.31378 | 0.00000 | -0.36374 |

Need help to investigate reason behind this.

I have checked that the values are not being modified from other part of the program.

I have checked that the values are not being modified from other part of the program.

Comment: Why are you using `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: *Need help to investigate reason behind this.* -- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Well, I happen to know EXACTLY who can give you all the "help to investigate reason behind this". And you already have it! It's your debugger!! It's a program on your computer that you can use to run your code, one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables, and see exactly what your program does, one step at a time! Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is mandatory skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. Have you tried using your debugger already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: Unless you have ***very*** specific requirements, you should always use `double` for all your floating point numbers and variables.

Comment: My guess would be undefined behaviour elsewhere in your program overwrote some memory resulting in an incorrect result. Try enabling address sanitizer

Comment: Does the simplified code do that, or only the full application code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/5d9ojvTqK. The calculated values match those expected pretty close.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I've already tried using debugger. Have observed that all the related values are computed as expected. I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. As of know, this is the only known occurrence of issue.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Simplified code does not do that. Only one known instance of issue reported for the full application code.

Comment: @DanielLangr: There is only one known occurence of this issue for the application. I'm also not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @VatsalTrivedi In that case, the problems is either in the application code we don't see or in the system itself. How can we help you if we don't know nothing about them. The code you posted is perfectly fine. The problem could be caused by anything from undefined behavior to RAM hardware problem. Is your application multi-threaded? Can you run it with the very same input as when the problem occured?

Comment: Then the simplified code is irrelevant, and what you have is essentially "I have had a problem with a big program once and I cannot reproduce it anymore". We can only give you general advice: use sanitizers and/or valgrind, compile with the highest possible warning level, use a fuzzer.

Comment: @DanielLangr: I've already run the application with the same input as when the problem occurred. The output I got is identical to the expected output. This is not a multithreaded application.

Comment: The difference in expected value and calculated value of avg_3 is around 0.3. Can it help to investigate what would have done wrong?

Comment: I would probably start with testing with more systematic inputs – all zeros; all ones; 1,2,3,4, ... ; -1, -2, -3, -4, ... and see if something in particular sticks out. Also, log the values as well as the averages.

Comment: @VatsalTrivedi *Need help to investigate reason behind this.* -- Sounds like you need to hire a consultant.   Other than "you need to debug further", no one can definitively tell you what is wrong with your code without knowing (and running) the entire application.